# How to retrieve results for a ParlAI Mturk sandbox assignment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk, parlai, mephisto

- I'm running a [ParlAI](https://github.com/facebookresearch/ParlAI/) task on Mturk sandbox using [Mephisto](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Mephisto/).
- I'm using the "[ParlAI Chat Task](https://github.com/facebookresearch/Mephisto/tree/master/examples/parlai_chat_task_demo)" code and followed the instructions given [here](https://parl.ai/docs/tutorial_crowdsourcing.html).
- I'm running the task from the ParlAI repo directory `ParlAI/parlai/crowdsourcing/tasks/chat_demo` using the command `python run.py mephisto/architect=heroku mephisto.provider.requester_name=my_name_mturk_sandbox mephisto.blueprint.num_conversations=5`.
- I'm using "Heroku" as the Mephisto architect.
- I'm able to connect through chat on the Mturk task with two different Mturk workers, complete the chat and submit the survey.
- But I'm unable to retrieve the chat and survey results submitted by the users through the Mturk HITs.

How do I retrieve the results for the assignments/tasks?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to set chat_data_folder parameter. This is the path where your data will be stored.

To set this parameter, add this part to your command :

```
mephisto.blueprint.chat_data_folder= 'give_a_path'
```